# How To Make this dropdown menu active after click? not after touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is JS, I try to change "touch" to "click", but nothing happens:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var touch   = $('#resp-menu');
    var menu    = $('.menu');

    $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 767 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

});
```

***You can see the full dropdown menu here:***
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygbpmV

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu li:hover>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

replace with

```
.menu li.active>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var touch   = $('#resp-menu');
    var menu    = $('.menu li');

    $(menu).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }).on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 767 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually setting the onclick function as it's supposed to be.
You can test this by writing this in the developers console.

```
var touch = $('#resp-menu');
touch.click();
```

The issue here is that the "touch" element can't be clicked because you can't see it.
Perhaps you should think again where do you want the event to happen.